# How to get a JS variable in a dialog button function

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, get

I have a dialog, in the dialog are dynamic buttons. In every button, a `$.get()` is generated.

The path to the file is partly variable, and the function (which will be executed on success) is variable too.

But I can't get it to work. The console says that the variables are `undefined`.
I know why, because it's in a `function`. But I set the variables globally.

Can anybody explain me how I can get these variables to work?

I will provide my source code so you can see what I mean.

---

### The source code

```
    var dialog_buttons = {};

    for(var i=0;i<socialMediaServ.length;i++)
    {
        dialog_buttons["Upload naar "+socialMediaServ[i]]= function()
        {
            $("#wait-dialog").dialog(
            {
                modal: true,
                resizable: false, 
                draggable: false,
                width:305,
                height:125,
                my:'center',
                at:'center',
                open: function(){}
            });

            $.get("../includes/social/"+socialMediaServ[i]+"/upload.php",{functie: "checkUser", fotonaam: fotoNaam}, window['users_'+socialMediaServ[i]+'_check'], 'json');
        }
    };
    dialog_buttons["Sluiten"]= function() 
    {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    };
    $("#dialog-foto").dialog("option", "buttons", dialog_buttons);
    $("#dialog-foto").dialog("open");
```

---

The variable `socialMediaServ` is set on the top of my page. `socialMediaServ` is an array with: `Facebook,Twitter`

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure I understand exactly what the problem is. I assume, that the socialMediaServ[i] value in the $.get is undefined.

I would try storing each array value in variable within the scope of the loop:

```
 for(var i=0;i<socialMediaServ.length;i++)
{
   (function(){
    dialog_buttons["Upload naar "+socialMediaServ[i]]= function()
    {
        $("#wait-dialog").dialog(
        {
            modal: true,
            resizable: false, 
            draggable: false,
            width:305,
            height:125,
            my:'center',
            at:'center',
            open: function(){}
        });

        $.get("../includes/social/"+socialMediaServ[i]+"/upload.php",{functie: "checkUser", fotonaam: fotoNaam}, window['users_'+socialMediaServ[i]+'_check'], 'json');
    }
  })(i);
};
```

Comment: Yes that works, but he now defines `twitter` in `../includes/social/"+socialM+"/upload.php` for both of the buttons (Facebook and Twitter)

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed the code sample and added a closure to store the i reference.

Comment: Ah thanks, with this part `var socialM = socialMediaServ[i];` in it just after `(function(){` it's working great! Many thanks for your help!